# Assigning match variables from nth match

Tags: perl

In the code which follows, I want `$a` and `$b` to be set to `02 02` (i.e. the values of the second match from `$l`) If I add a line `($a,$b)=($1,$2);`, it works but I'd rather do it in a single line if possible.

Can someone let me know what's wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $l = "01:01 02:02";

my ($a,$b);

if ( ($a,$b) = ( ( $l =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d)/g)[1] ) ) {

  print "12 $1 $2\n";
  print "ab $a $b\n";

}
```

Output:

```
12 02 02
Use of uninitialized value $b in concatenation (.) or string at ./gs.pl line 11.
ab 01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use `$a` or `$b` as variable names.  Those are used by `sort` - and you'll start to wonder what's going on if you end up sorting in this same scope.

So, for lack of better names, let's try `$h` and `$m`.

So, now, what does `$l =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d)/g` return in list context?  It returns all the values it found: `("01","01","02","02")`.  Now do you see why `[1]` doesn't get what you're looking for?

Depending on what you're doing, this may be as simple as using `[-2,-1]` as the index lookup (to always get the last two).  Or it may be that you want to loop through all the pairings and do something. There's not enough context, but that should give you some idea to go on with.